# AngularJs communication from one page to another

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to transfer a variable from one page to another using AngularJS. I looked up the net but what I found merely transferred the value on the same HTML page within two controllers. Can someone help me out here so as to get this right I have added the code below. It may also be me making an error in the code its just I am not able to figure it out.

JavaScript Code

```
var app = angular.module("appLive", []);
app.factory('SharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var something;
    var setSomething = function(something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
    var getSomething = function() {
        return something;
    }
    return {
        setSomething: setSomething,
        getSomething: getSomething
    }
});
app.controller("CTRL1", function($scope, SharedService) {
    $scope.transfer = function(value) {
        SharedService.setSomething(value)
        console.log("Value Transfered")
    }
});
app.controller("CTRL2", function($scope, SharedService) {
    $scope.initFunction = function() {
        $scope.message = SharedService.getSomething();
    }
});
```

HTML Page 1

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Communication Page 1</title>
        <SCRIPT src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.js"></SCRIPT>
        <script src = "JavaScriptCode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app = "appLive" ng-controller="CTRL1">
            <input type = "text" ng-model = "dataInput">
            <br><br>
            <button ng-click = "transfer(dataInput)">Transfer the value</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML Page 2

```
<html>
     <head>
        <title>Angular Communication Page 2</title>
        <SCRIPT src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.js"></SCRIPT>
        <script src = "OnlineJavaScriptCode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app = "myModule" ng-controller="ControllerOne" ng-init = "initFunction()">
            <input type = "text" ng-model = "message">
            <br><br>
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add routing in it now, or use ng-hide/ng-show

Comment: You have two separated pages with two main modules, then you need to use localStorage to get variable from one page to the other. You can create service that will read/write localStorage that will be shared by two pages.

Comment: I do not mind Using the localStorage since in the main project I need to use multiple servers to work from. I tried creating a global variable outside the module class but even that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using angular right.
The code you've presented is of two different application (angular modules) that are not aware of one another so start by creating a single application module that may consume the two different modules (either by DI or by just changing all the code registered under them to the be registered under the same module.

In order to navigate between the two different views (pages) you should use the angular [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) / [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) modules.

If you're trying to pass data from one domain to another you should do it via server and not the client.

In the current setup there's no angular way to pass data as for each module a different app will be bootstrapped and the pre opened app will get destroyed.

If you're on the same domain you may use localStorage or sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your exact question, you can use localStorage to share data between two pages in the same domain (and if you have two domains you can read [this article](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/)).

You can create service that will be used in both pages (included in both modules):

```
var module = angular.module('common', []);
module.factory('SharedService', function() {
   return {
       setSomething = function(value) {
           localStorage.setItem('something', value);
       },
       getSomething = function() {
           return localStorage.getItem('something');
       }
   };
});
```

and you can use this module in both pages:

```
angular.module("appLive", ['common']);


angular.module("myModule", ['common']);
```

if you have opened those two pages in two tabs and want to send the variable from one page to the other (so the message variable get populated when you call transfer) then you will need to use storage event or you can use [sysend.js library](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js) that use this event to send messages to other pages/tabs.

But if you're building app you should probably use one page and one main module and use ui-router or ng-route to create routes that will have different url and based on that open different view as described by @obyFS.